# "Ad populum" idiom

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, meaning

Is "ad populum" ever seen as an idiom for "popular", or can it only mean "to the people"? For example, if something is considered popular, would "ad populum" be an acceptable phrase to use?

Answer (score 3):

*Ad populum* is such a common phrase that searching for such a particular usage could be quite tedious. Offhand, I can think of no example.

You could simply use *popularis*, though it's more usual to use a circumlocution to describe someone or something as 'popular'. A phrase such as *in vulgus acceptus* has the precise meaning; similarly *studium populi habere* and *coram populo gratus* (and, no doubt, several others) might serve well enough in many situations.